# Probability - not sure where to start with this?

Tags: probability

A mod can feel free to adjust the title as needed - I don't even know what to title this.

I have a question (yes, for homework) that I'm not sure where to even start on really. It's not a probability class, but we were expected to have *rudimentary knowledge* of probability and statistics. I apparently don't have that...

I'm not looking for the answer right out, I'd really just like to know what I could read up on, and maybe how to get started for this?

Below is the question:

> A collision happens when both nodes select the same slot among the 2 slots available
>
> Suppose nodes $A$ and $B$ are ready to send data at the same time. In the $i$th round
> after $i-1$ collisions have already occurred, the two nodes wait $0, 1,\dots , 2^{i−1}$ slots until the next attempt, all $2^{i−1}$ choices having
> equal probability.
>
> Find the probability $q_i$ of a collision in the $i$th round, given that there are collisions in the previous $i−1$ rounds (i.e. $q_1 = 1$, $q_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}$), for all $i \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not completely clear to me; what do you mean by "among the $2$ slots available"? After that you say "wait $0,1,\ldots,2^{i-1}$ slots", which makes me believe "slots" all natural numbers, actually.

Well, assuming the question is as I understood it, here's a simplification of the question: two fair die (with faces $0,1,\ldots,2^{i-1}$) are rolled; what are the chances both will hit the same number.

The answer for that is easy, but you haven't asked for it.